# Flot line chart - How to change static value to load from ajax url

Tags: jquery, ajax, flot

I have a flot line graph which is loading data from a static javascript array.

```
  d1 = [
    [1262304000000, 5], [1264982400000, 200], [1267401600000, 1605], [1270080000000, 1129], 
    [1272672000000, 1163], [1275350400000, 1905], [1277942400000, 2002], [1280620800000, 2917], 
    [1283299200000, 2700], [1285891200000, 2700], [1288569600000, 2100], [1291161600000, 1700]
  ]

  d2 = [
    [1262304000000, 434], [1264982400000, 232], [1267401600000, 475], [1270080000000, 553],
    [1272672000000, 675], [1275350400000, 679], [1277942400000, 789], [1280620800000, 1026], 
    [1283299200000, 1640], [1285891200000, 1892], [1288569600000, 2147], [1291161600000, 2256]
  ]

  data = [{ 
    label: "Total visitors", 
    data: d1
  }, {
    label: "Total Sales",
    data: d2
  }]

  var holder = $('#line-chart')
  if (holder.length) {
    $.plot(holder, data, chartOptions )
  }
```

I have a java url in my web application that returns this json. It's very similar but not 100% in the same format.

```
{"label":"This Year","data":[[1423659600000,28192],[1423746000000,33216],[1423832400000,31314],[1423918800000,22875],[1424005200000,20792],[1424091600000,20151],[1424178000000,22424]]}
```

I need some help on whether I can plot my graph using that json and also I'm pretty new to ajax and need some help on how I would run the ajax call, store the data in a variable and then plot the graph. I need to call the ajax url and plot once for each series on the graph.

Sorry for asking for so much detail. But I'm a bit lost because I can't find many examples on how to do what I am looking to do.

---

### Edit

For anyone else needing help with this I manage to solve my problem by doing something like this....

```
  fetchData(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
  });

function fetchData(callback) {

    $.when(fetchThisYearsData(), fetchLastYearsData()).done(function (dataThisYear, dataLastYear) {
        var data = [];
        data.push(dataThisYear[0]);
        data.push(dataLastYear[0]);
        callback(data);
    });
}



function fetchThisYearsData() {
    // NOTE:  This function must return the value 
    //        from calling the $.ajax() method.
    return $.getJSON( "service/tranAnalysis/tranCounts.json?siteId=1&yearOffset=0", function(json) {});     
}

function fetchLastYearsData() {
    // NOTE:  This function must return the value 
    //        from calling the $.ajax() method.
    return $.getJSON( "service/tranAnalysis/tranCounts.json?siteId=1&yearOffset=1", function(json) {})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite okay, we were all learning once!

But that's exactly why I won't give you a full example, you will learn much more.

For Ajax, use JQuery or similar library. It makes things a lot easier:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

If you specify JSON as return type, it will parse it into a Javascript object automatically. Alternatively you can use the native JSON object to parse & stringify data.

You just have one data set (with the right properties), so you can simply add it to an array and provide to flot like:

```
var data = [json_data];
var holder = $('#line-chart')
if (holder.length) {
   $.plot(holder, data, chartOptions);
}
```

If you need to redraw the graph with a new data set:

```
data.push(new_json);
plot.setData(data);
plot.setupGrid(); //only necessary if your new data will change the axes or grid
plot.draw();
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It helps me. I'll try it out tomorrow. As mentioned I have a seperate ajax call for each series. Can I call $plot multiple times(each time with a different series) for each ajax call ?

Comment: Yes and no. If you load all the series at once you shouldn't have to, just add them all into the same array before calling $.plot

If you need to load a new series later on, add the new series to the existing array & see update above.

Comment: Thanks for this. After spending a whole day learning how to write callbacks from ajax calls in jquery (which I now understand) I think i have the data in the write format now and posted what I did in the edit. I am still having issues loading the graph and am getting a flot error. But I think that should be started in a new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622272/flot-line-chart-error