# flot - line chart error

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm trying to plot a line graph using flot and I'm having some troubles. Admittedly I'm very new to flot.

My data array is loaded from ajax calls. I think I have the data in the right format but when my page loads I'm getting an error in jquery.flot.js.

[image]

Here is my javascript to load the float graph. I'm in particular looking for some advice on my x-axis specification. I don't think I have it specified right. i.e. I don't understand ticks and what they are in relation to the graph.

I've shown the json loaded from each call in the comments in the json functions.

thanks

```
$(function () {    
  var data, chartOptions
  fetchData(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
  });

  chartOptions = {
    xaxis: {
      mode: "time",
      timeformat: "%Y/%m/%d",
      tickSize: [1, "day"],
      tickLength: 0
    },
    yaxis: {

    },
    series: {
      lines: {
        show: true, 
        fill: false,
        lineWidth: 3
      },
      points: {
        show: true,
        radius: 3,
        fill: true,
        fillColor: "#ffffff",
        lineWidth: 2
      }
    },
    grid: { 
      hoverable: true, 
      clickable: false, 
      borderWidth: 0 
    },
    legend: {
      show: true
    },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
      content: '%s: %y'
    },
    colors: ['#D74B4B', '#475F77', '#BCBCBC', '#777777', '#6685a4', '#E68E8E']
  }    

  var holder = $('#line-chart')

  if (holder.length) {
    $.plot(holder, data, chartOptions )
  }

})


function fetchData(callback) {

    $.when(fetchThisYearsData(), fetchLastYearsData()).done(function (dataThisYear, dataLastYear) {
        var data = [];
        data.push(dataThisYear[0]);
        data.push(dataLastYear[0]);
        callback(data);
    });
}

function fetchThisYearsData() {
    // returns {"label":"This Year","data":[[1423746000000,33216],[1423832400000,31314],[1423918800000,22875],[1424005200000,20795],[1424091600000,20151],[1424178000000,22448],[1424264400000,26996]]}
    return $.getJSON( "service/tranAnalysis/tranCounts.json?siteId=1&yearOffset=0", function(json) {});     
}

function fetchLastYearsData() {
    // returns {"label":"Last Year","data":[[1392469200000,21477],[1392555600000,18664],[1392642000000,19149],[1392728400000,20415],[1392814800000,24617],[1392901200000,30278],[1392987600000,28808]]}
    return $.getJSON( "service/tranAnalysis/tranCounts.json?siteId=1&yearOffset=1", function(json) {})
}
```

Comment: Isn't `d` supposed to be `data`? Where do you define `d` and what do you assign it?

Comment: Hi...Not sure what you mean. d is the variable inside the flot.js file (look to the right of the error) for the file name. It's their variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that $.getJSON is an async ajax function.
It provides data to the callback.
You are setting the callback but the data isn't going anywhere.

You can make the call synchronous by changing you getData functions to this:

```
return $.ajax({
  url: "service/tranAnalysis/tranCounts.json?siteId=1&yearOffset=0",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false
});
```

I think there may also be some problems with your use of $.when but see how your go with this first and report back.

Comment: Crap. I spent all day the other day trying to understand call backs. Looks like I still didn't get it quite right. I'll try this soon. Is there another way to do it becUse from what I have read most ppl have said not to make ajax calls non synchronous. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for this comment. As you have worked out by now this is an issue with my understanding if how ajax works  and your comment had helped me solved my problem. I will mark this as solved for now until I fix. Until that time I've decided to test my flot graph with static values which in the most part is working. Thanks again